# Shmget error, invalid argument when size greater than 4

Tags: c, macos, unix, gcc, shared-memory

### When using Shmget I'm facing issues with using sizes over 4 bytes.

`test_shmid = shmget(foo_key, 4, IPC_CREAT | 0666);` and below?

No issues.

---

`test_shmid = shmget(foo_key, 5, IPC_CREAT | 0666);` and above?

Returns -1 (fails) with error: **Invalid argument**

---

I figured this may be an issue with SHMAX but upon investigation I found: `kern.sysv.shmmax:4194304` so I don't believe that's the case. I also looked into SHMSEG but ruled it out as I can create multiple segments of size 4 just fine but it only errors when I throw in one of size 5 or above.

Memory segment already being associated with given key doesn't seem to be the issue as I've tested a handful of random, new keys and have also reused keys only changing the size parameter and, as expected, the segment is created just fine when size is below 5.

Using OSX 10.13.6 on 64-bit architecture and compiling with GCC, any tips on where to look next or insight into what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to [the official POSIX reference for `shmget`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html) the error `EINVAL` can mean *either* "A shared memory segment is to be created and the value of size is less than the system-imposed minimum or greater than the system-imposed maximum." *or* "No shared memory segment is to be created and a shared memory segment exists for key but the size of the segment associated with it is less than size.". macOS could add more conditions (you have to find its specific man page). Do any of these conditions apply?

Comment: Man page section on ```EINVAL``` only states "No shared memory segment is to be created, and a shared memory segment exists for key, but the size of the segment associated with it is less than size, which is non-zero.". I'm not certain how to interpret this in relation to the issues as it states a shared memory segment exists for key but again throwing new and random keys at it yields the same issue. Many thanks for commenting btw @Someprogrammerdude